# Difficult XML to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I am finding difficult parsing this XML:

```
<menuItems>
    <menuItem>
        <text>Auto 4-spd, 6 cyl, 3.8 L, 3.8N</text>
        <value>14864</value>
    </menuItem>
    <menuItem>
        <text>Auto 4-spd, 8 cyl, 4.6 L</text>
        <value>14866</value>
    </menuItem>
    <menuItem>
        <text>Man 5-spd, 6 cyl, 3.8 L</text>
        <value>14865</value>
    </menuItem>
</menuItems>
```

I am doing it like this:

```
list = []
response = et.XML(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
for i, child in enumerate(response):
    for subchild in child:
        lista.append({subchild.tag : subchild.text})
```

So when I print the list, item by item, I receive this:

```
{'text': 'Auto 4-spd, 6 cyl, 3.8 L, 3.8N'}
{'value': '14864'}
{'text': 'Auto 4-spd, 8 cyl, 4.6 L'}
{'value': '14866'}
{'text': 'Man 5-spd, 6 cyl, 3.8 L'}
{'value': '14865'}
```

Instead of that, I would like to receive something like this:

```
{'Auto 4-spd, 6 cyl, 3.8 L, 3.8N': '14864'}
{'Auto 4-spd, 8 cyl, 4.6 L': '14866'}
{'Man 5-spd, 6 cyl, 3.8 L': '14865'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lista = []
response = et.XML(xml)
for i, child in enumerate(response):
    text = child.find('text').text
    value = child.find('value').text
    lista.append({text: value})
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I print an item of the list I get: {<Element 'text' at 0x7f39bdc9dd68>: <Element 'value' at 0x7f39bdc9dea8>}

Comment: It seems like you are missing the `.text`